# Re: Response card error: Not showing up on Facebook Messenger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, aws-lex

I am also facing an issue to display a response card button on facebook page. I created a chatbot which is working fine in aws lex console but when I connect it with the facebook page the response card buttons are not displaying on facebook page only text message pop up.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely with required fields not being filled out. Be sure to have messages, messaging-postbacks, and messaging-optins selected in Page Subscriptions. Next, make sure you give a valid image URL in the response card and that both "Title" and "Subtitle" are filled with nonempty strings. Finally, keep in mind that Facebook Messenger will only render your first three buttons on the response card, as the Messenger API has a limit in the number of buttons which can be attached to a response card. This worked for me, but it's a bit lamentable the Lex docs are sparse and the tools quite rigid. Hope it works!

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I found that the "Title" field is a required field in the response card button. It can not be left empty. When I filled the 'Title' field, the response card button is working fine on the Facebook page. Thank You for the clarification Peter Wofford.